# Is it possible for double-escaping to cause harm to the DB?

Tags: database, database-security

If I accidentally double escape a string, can the DB be harmed?

*For the purposes of this question, let's say I'm not using stored procedures or parametrized queries*

For example, let's say I get the following input:

```
bob's bike
```

And I escape that:

```
bob\'s bike
```

But my code is horrible, and escapes it again:

```
bob\\\'s bike
```

Now, if I insert that into a DB, the value in the DB will be

```
bob\'s bike
```

Which, while is not what I want, won't harm the DB. Is it possible for any input that's double escaped to do something malicious to the DB assuming that I take all other necessary security precautions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single escaping is equally as harmful/harmless as double escaping in terms of security.

The biggest issue is that you need to double-unescape. Otherwise, if you only single-unescape, you will end up with backslashes in database output.

For example, if you run `bob\\\'s bike` through the unescape() function, it will output `bob\'s bike` which will then be printed to the page, unless you unescape it again. But don't unescape too many times, because this can remove intentional backslashes (and possibly do more harm).

Does this question have anything to do with PHP's magic quotes feature by chance? Just curious...

Answer (score 1):

> assuming that I take all other
>   necessary security precautions

Hardcoding SQL and/or parameter values into an application should never be considered "taking the necessary security precautions", because you will always be subject to SQL injection attacks (in the case of a web application).

It's best to use stored procedures if you can, and if that's not an option, at a minimum you should be using parameterized queries (bind variables is another term for this).

But to answer your question, storing `bob\'s bike` in the database isn't going to do any harm in and of itself, but take care to consider the other points mentioned above, they are vitally important from a security perspective.